# How to parse string timestamp to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying  parse string timestamp to `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");

String requestTimestamp = "2020-11-27 18:04:31+0";
String endDate ="2020-12-25 23:59:59+0";
final Long between = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(LocalDateTime.parse(endDate,formatter), LocalDateTime.parse(requestTimestamp,formatter));
```

Getting below exception:

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-12-25 23:59:59+0' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

Can any you please help me what is wrong in my code. Why I am getting `DateTimeParseException`?

Comment: I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code.

1. As with your pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX` , the input does not contain `2020-11-27 18:04:31+0` .SSS part (fraction-of-second)
2. `+0` in your input has to be `+00` for Zone offset. If you are having zero as zone offset, make your input to be of form `2020-11-27 18:04:31Z` with pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX`

Below is a working code,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX");

String requestTimestamp = "2020-11-27 18:04:31Z";
String endDate = "2020-12-25 23:59:59Z";
```

Adding two last cents, If you have control over input, it is always suggested to go with Predefined Formatters. I feel [ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) will suit your need.

Comment: requestTimestamp  and endDate  are dynamic . So I can't change values.
value format is always 2020-11-27 18:04:31+0. in this casw which formatter I have to use it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You either need to replace +0 with +00 or with Z. Your input is not adhering to any standards.

Comment: @madhusudhan when these values are “dynamic ”, I suppose that means generated, it *should* be possible to fix the generator to produce a standard format, like the suggested iso instant (ISO 8601). What you have here, is two parties wasting their development time, one to generate non-standard formatted strings, another to parse the non-standard formatted strings. Both could have a much easier life.